# Pass variable value to query in for loop

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have a list comprised of several queries which are executed by a for loop. I would like to prompt the user to enter the origin (ilink) that will be utilized by the fourth query in the list.

The script runs fine when the origin is manually defined within the query. I have tried the following syntax which have all failed:

```
cursor.execute(lines, ilink)
cursor.execute(lines, [ilink])
cursor.execute(lines, (ilink))
```

I have also run the script with each query defined in its own cursor.execute(query) which accepts the argument, but does not pass any results due to multiple cursors.

```
import MySQLdb
ilink = raw_input("Choose and ilink to query (include 199N):" )
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="host",user="user",passwd="pass")
queries = [
"""USE monthly_audit;""",
"""DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS monthly_audit.tmp_order_ids;""",
"""DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS monthly_audit.tmp_internalselect;""",
"""CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE monthly_audit.tmp_order_ids AS
(SELECT DISTINCT order_id AS orders
FROM ng_tradeserver_db_history.fix_execution_reports_201906
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP/1000000) >=  '2019-06-19 16:59:59'
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP/1000000) <= '2019-06-20 23:59:59'
AND TargetCompID = %s);""",]
cursor = db.cursor()
for lines in queries:
    lines.split(",")
    cursor.execute(lines, [ilink])
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

**This is only the relevant snippet of sql, total query is over 500 lines*

I expect the script to run the set of queries and return the results of said query to be stored in a csv. I am currently getting the following error when executing:
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: If the queries are actually in a list just like you show us, then you should get rid of this line: `lines.split(",")`

Comment: Thanks, but not helpful to the problem at hand.

Comment: have you tried using format? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your questions correct, but you can try using fstrings. I believe the quotes cause the problems during the string formatting.

Example:

```
query = f'''select ID, lat, lon from tbl order by st_distance(tbl.geom,st_setsrid(st_makepoint({lon},{lat}), 4326)) asc limit 1;'''
cursor.execute(query)
```

In this query the {lon}, {lat} are variables. Have a look at the docs for f strings https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html

Comment: I am using Python 2.7, would this still be compatible?

Comment: I was looking at the issue in the wrong light. I should have been looking how to pass variables into a string. I ended up formatting the last query in the following fashion:
    AND TargetCompID = {}.""".format(ilinks)